# How to create a dictionary based off CSV file

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

I have a csv file with the following format:

```
#ID #Number #Date #Name #Email
1978 26   24/4/10 Jim  Jim@randomemail.com
1328 31   22/7/10 Jim  Kim@randomemail.com
1908 26   21/4/10 Jim  Dim@randomemail.com
1918 26   29/4/10 Jim  Rim@randomemail.com
1938 46   24/4/10 Jim  Lim@randomemail.com
```

I have opened the csv file and printed it out already.

I now want to make it so it's made into a dictionary such as:
     [ID: 1978, Number : 26, Date : 24/4/10, Name : Jim, Email : 
     Jim@randomemail.com], [etc], [etc]

I know this is probably very easy but I'm new and have been stuck for a few hours.

Comment: Have you seen [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code written in pure python that'll do the trick:

```
for line in file_contents_2:
    line_contents = line.strip().split(",") # Removes the \n,
    # then turns the line into a list, where each value is seperated
    # by the comma      
    the_dictionary = {}
    reference = ["ORIN","DEST","HORIZ","BEAR"]
    for i in range(4): # iterates i=0 to i=3
        # Arrays start at 0, so a=[1,2,3]; a[1] would return 2
        the_dictionary[reference[i]] = line_contents[i]
    dictionary_list.append(the_dictionary)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've added this to my code but nothing seems to happen?https://imgur.com/a/7WadhrF

Comment: I didn't include the print statement. The code I wrote is meant to replace lines 26-38 in your original picture

Answer (score 4):

Following up on my comment, consider something like:

```
import csv
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('#ID', '1978'), ('#Number', '26'), ('#Date', '24/4/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Jim@randomemail.com')])
OrderedDict([('#ID', '1328'), ('#Number', '31'), ('#Date', '22/7/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Kim@randomemail.com')])
OrderedDict([('#ID', '1908'), ('#Number', '26'), ('#Date', '21/4/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Dim@randomemail.com')])
OrderedDict([('#ID', '1918'), ('#Number', '26'), ('#Date', '29/4/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Rim@randomemail.com')])
OrderedDict([('#ID', '1938'), ('#Number', '46'), ('#Date', '24/4/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Lim@randomemail.com')])
```

The two extra arguments to `DictReader` are necessary to get your variable-space-delimited file to parse correctly.

Or, if you want all the rows at once, something like:

```
import csv
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    rows = list(reader)

print(rows)
```

produces

```
[
    OrderedDict([('#ID', '1978'), ('#Number', '26'), ('#Date', '24/4/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Jim@randomemail.com')]), 
    OrderedDict([('#ID', '1328'), ('#Number', '31'), ('#Date', '22/7/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Kim@randomemail.com')]), 
    OrderedDict([('#ID', '1908'), ('#Number', '26'), ('#Date', '21/4/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Dim@randomemail.com')]), 
    OrderedDict([('#ID', '1918'), ('#Number', '26'), ('#Date', '29/4/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Rim@randomemail.com')]), 
    OrderedDict([('#ID', '1938'), ('#Number', '46'), ('#Date', '24/4/10'), ('#Name', 'Jim'), ('#Email', 'Lim@randomemail.com')])
]
```

and,

```
print(rows[0]["#Email"])
```

produces

```
Jim@randomemail.com
```

**Update**

If your file is actually *tab* delimited, you could use:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
```

You should be able to tell what the delimiter by printing the line (as you already have), but wrap it in a `repr` call -- something like `print(repr(line))`.  If you see a `\t` in the output, it's tab delimited.

Comment: I think the delimiter is a '\t' (tab) not space, but that's jut my reading.

Comment: @hd1 That's possible, my editor auto-replaces -- I'll add alternative Reader arguments

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas will make your life much easier:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_csv')
your_dict = df.to_dict()
```

That's it, there are some optional arguments in `to_dict` to help you format it the way you want.